# Pybrains Maze tutorial gets Error

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, maze

I am trying to do Maze question by using pybrains
here is my question:
I followed the tutorial and run example

```
envmatrix = [[...]]
env = Maze(envmatrix, (1, 8))
task = MDPMazeTask(env)
table = ActionValueTable(states_nr, actions_nr)
table.initialize(0.)
learner = Q()
agent = LearningAgent(table, learner)
experiment = Experiment(task, agent)
```

when I run and showed

```
assert self.lastobs != None
FutureWarning: comparison to `None` will result in an elementwise object comparison in the future.
```

Could anyone helps me?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid this specific warning I would suggest using [`numpy.not_equal`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.not_equal.html#numpy.not_equal):

```
np.not_equal(self.lastobs, None)
```

Anyway the problem arises from the fact that you are comparing a list of objects with `None` which will cause an element-wise comparison (each object will be compared with `None` in turn). This is it's warning you about. You can also ignore it.

Comment: thanks your answer!
I notice that another one is  "assert self.lastaction != None"
Is this same idea like lastobs, i can rewrite?

Comment: @Benny Yes you can re-write both of them no problem. (or ignore them like I said)